# Angular js $http factory patterns

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I've a factory named as 'userService'.

```
.factory('userService', function($http) {
    var users = [];

    return {
        getUsers: function(){
            return $http.get("https://www.yoursite.com/users").then(function(response){
                users = response;
                return users;
            });
        },
        getUser: function(index){
            return users[i];
        }
    }
})
```

In the first page, On button click I want to call getUsers function and it will return the 'users' array.

I want to use 'users' array in the second page. How can I do it?

P.s: I'm using getters and setters to store the response in first page and access the same in second page. Is this the way everyone doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pattern i have followed in  my own project. You can see the code below

```
.factory('userService', function($http) {
return {
        serviceCall : function(urls, successCallBack) {

                $http({
                    method : 'post',
                    url : url,
                    timeout : timeout
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        commonDataFactory.setResponse(data);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        commonDataFactory.setResponse({"data":"undefined"});
                        alert("error");
                });
            }
        },
    };
```

### After service call set the response data in common data factory so that it will be accessible throughout the app

In the above code I've used common data factory to store the response.

Answer (score 3):

**1). getUsers**. For consistence sake I would still use the same service method on the second page but I would also add data caching logic:

```
.factory('userService', function($q, $http) {

    var users;

    return {
        getUsers: function() {
            return users ? $q.when(users) : $http.get("https://www.yoursite.com/users").then(function(response) {
                users = response;
                return users;
            });
        },
        getUser: function(index){
            return users[i];
        }
    };
});
```

Now on the second page usage is the same as it was on the first:

```
userService.getUsers().then(function(users) {
    $scope.users = users;
});
```

but this promise will resolve immediately because users are already loaded and available.

**2). getUser**. Also it makes sense to turn `getUser` method into asynchronous as well:

```
getUser: function(index){
    return this.getUsers().then(function(users) {
        return users[i];
    });
}
```

and use it this way in controller:

```
userService.getUser(123).then(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
});
```

Comment: It might also be prudent to include logic in the `getUser()` method to handle cases where `users` is empty or null.

Comment: @Brett I agree. However I still have doubts here what approach is better here: throwing an error in case `getUser` is called when users are not available, or make `getUser` also return promise like `getUsers`.

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for the answer. What I did was I've created two functions first one for service call and in that i've assigned response to data. In the second function I am returning the data. However If I repeatedly make service calls the same data was carry forwarding. I hope your answer will solve the problem. :)

Comment: @dfsq I've a same doubt when the data is not available what is better approach? should we do post processing in factory itself or should we do it in controller?

Comment: @GangadharJannu I would go with making `getUser` also return promise, like I described in point #2 of my answer. This way we are sure that user is retrieved always after users array is available.

Comment: @dfsq in that case you are again hitting service call which is not appropriate. Isn't it?

Comment: No, if you are calling `getUser()` before users are available (getUsers has never been called) then getUser internally call getUsers for you.